# Escaping -> and => when parsing HTML using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I need to parse and return the tagname and the attributes in our PHP code files:

```
<ct:tagname attr="attr1" attr="attr2">
```

For this purpose the following regular expression has been constructed:

```
(\<ct:([^\s\>]*)([^\>]*)\>)
```

This expression works as expected but it breaks when the following code is parsed

```
<ct:form/input type="attr1" value="$item->field">
```

The original regular expression breaks because of the > character in the $item->field. I would need to construct a regular expression that ignores the -> or => but not the single >.

I am open to any suggestions... Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using negative lookbehind like that:

```
(\<ct:([^\s\>]*)(.*?)(?<!-|=)\>)
```

Matches :

```
<ct:tagname attr="attr1" attr="attr2">
<ct:form/input type="attr1" value="$item->field">
```

Not sure that it the best suited solution for your case, but that respects the constraints.

Comment: But it causes evitable backtracking.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<ct:([^\s\>]*)((?:\s+\w+\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')\s*)*)>
```

But if that’s XML, use should better use a XML parser.

Comment: +1 for ‘use an XML parser’. You can't parse XML reliably with regex, full stop.

Answer (score 1):

In general, any parsing problem rapidly runs into language constructs that are context-free but not regular.  It may be a better[1] solution to write a context-free parser, ignoring everything except the elements you're interested in.

[1] "better" as seen from a viewpoint of Being The Right Thing, not necessarily a return on investment one.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is not recognize the `->` and `=>`, but ignore everything between pairs of quotes.

I think it can be done by inserting ((

```
("[^"]*")*
```

)) at the opportune place.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to match to the attributes in the same expression.

```
\<ct:([^\s\>]*)((([a-x0-9]+)=\"([^\"]*)\")*)\>
```

**edit:** removed part about > not being valid [xml](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax) in attribute values.

Comment: ‘>’ in an attirbute value is perfectly well-formed XML.